# change css for every 4th row

Tags: php, javascript, sql, css

I want to display every 4th row grabbed from the database with different CSS:

```
<div class="last"></div>
```

but the rest of them should be displayed normaly:

```
<div></div>
```

I am using simple query to grab data from database:

```
SELECT LEN(column_name) FROM table_name
```

I saw this type of thing but I don't remember how to do it properly. Any ideas?

Comment: Please post the PHP code you're using.

Comment: Added CSS and Javascript tags as they (along with php) are the best options for dynamically applying classes to a table of data.

Answer (score 6):

using css [like](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-nthchild)

```
tr:nth-child(4n) {  
   background-color:yellow;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
<div<?php echo $i % 4 == 0 ? ' class="last"' : '' ?>>...</div>
```

Use % to get division remainder, if it equals zero then it is exatly forth div and we need to print it with class, otherwise print nothing.

Answer (score 4):

This is not the sort of thing you should do in SQL. Have a variable in PHP act as a counter starting from 0, and use the alternate class when the modulus of 4 of the counter is 3.

Answer (score 4):

```
<?php 
    $query = "SELECT LEN(column_name) FROM table_name";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    $i = 1;
    echo  "<table>";
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo  "<tr><td>";
        echo  "<p";
        if ($i % 4 == 0) print " class='stripe'";
       echo  ">" . $row['item'] . "</p></td></tr>";
        $i++;
     }
    echo  "</table>";
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

the qustion is absurd  I dnt ustand why you are trying to set your css style in the db.. its illogical to do so and you will unnecessarily increase the complexity of your query.

Anyways my suggestion would be to do the same in your web tier i.e once you retrieve the records from the db and rendering the page. just write sm logic that will add the css class..

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
<?php 
    $query = "SELECT LEN(column_name) FROM table_name";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    $i = 1;
    print "<table>";
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        print "<tr><td>";
        print "<p";
        if ($i % 4 == 0) print " class='stripe'";
        print ">" . $row['item'] . "</p></td></tr>";
        $i++;
     }
     print "</table>";
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't do it with SQL queries, do it with PHP:

```
  $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table_name");
  $i = 1;    
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
     $class = ($i % 4 == 0) ? ' last' : '';        
     echo '<div class="'.$class.'"></div>';
     $i++;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how Bootstrap [does it](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v4-dev/dist/css/bootstrap.css#L1709)

```
.table-striped tbody tr:nth-child(odd) {  
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}
```

So you can create your own class and replace `odd` with `4n`

```
.table-striped-4th tbody tr:nth-child(4n) {  
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child